# Search an HTML document for facebook page URL and twitter URL

Tags: php, html, curl

I am scraping data from some sites, so in the response HTML code I would like to fetch facebook page links and twitter account links if there are any.
Sample of one html code fetched is given below: 
Note: I am using CURL module o fetch data.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Example-page-16149277784545354/" target="_blank">
<div class="template asset" data-id="4722053" contenteditable="false">
<figure>
........
</figure>
</div>
</a>
```

I need that facebook page link inside 'href' attribute , and same for twitter account links.

Comment: It would be much easier to use a scraping tool like `beautifulsoup` which is written in python.  Here is a post about scraping in PHP http://www.jacobward.co.uk/working-with-the-scraped-data-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code. But this is a rough workaround, this loop may go infinite. Please test it and correct it if wrong.

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$i = -1;
while(strpos("href='",$i)>=0){
   $strpos = strpos("href='",$i);
   $i2 = strpos("'",$i+7);
   $link = substr($str,$strpos,$i2);
   $i = $i2 + 1;
  //now check if the link is facebook, twitter etc.
}
//do the same with while(strpos("href=\"",$i)>=0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check it with regex, here is an example for a facebook check:

```
$testString = '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Example-page-16149277784545354/" target="_blank">
<div class="template asset" data-id="4722053" contenteditable="false">
<figure>
........
</figure>
</div>
</a>';

$facebookPattern = '/"(http[s]{0,1}:\/\/www\.facebook\.com[^"]+)"/';
preg_match_all($facebookPattern, $testString, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

see also https://regex101.com/r/sW7eV1/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple html dom, it provides an object oriented interface.
you can just provide the url to the the function which fetches and parses the html into an object. you can call properties and methods on that object to access elements of the dom.

for reference:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm